Why is my GitHub scheduled workflow not triggering?
Having some trouble with a GitHub Actions workflow not executing on a schedule as expected.
Reproduced my issue using a simplified workflow. The workflow below has been comitted to my repository as .github/workflows/schedule-test.yml in my master branch.
I've confirmed that the default branch for the repository is master.
I'm expecting this action to run once every five minutes, and it's not.
I have also tried */10 * * * * and */15 * * * * and those aren't working either.
Pretty sure this is one of those "you missed something small but super obvious in hindsight" type of things. Any assistance welcome.
name: Schedule Test

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/5 * * * *"

jobs:

    test:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        steps:
            - name: Log test
              run: echo "Test"


Posting the solution as an answer proper is the right thing to do when you solve your own question. Thanks for posting it!

Thanks halfer. And yeah, I tried to mark my answer as the solution yesterday, but the system wouldn't let me. That's why I edited it into the question, to make it obvious to people it was solved to save them wasting their time opening it. I still can't mark my answer as the solution yet, looks like I have a 7 hour wait to go before I can do that.

Don't worry about any delay to accepting a self-answer. Accepting an answer does not "close" a question, as more answers can still be made, and they are still welcome. We still would rather not have answer material in questions - it keeps questions readable if they just contain question material. Thanks!

Nevermind. It wasn't working for the last few hours of me trying to get it up and running. But now, suddenly, it's working.
Action isn't actually going once every five minutes - more like once every 8 minutes or so.
But in any case: It's firing, so I know I've got the syntax right at least. I must have just attempted this right in a window when GitHub was being weird.
